# Is there a way to delay the segue action until after the user picks an image through their photo library or takes a photo? SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, camera, segue

I am fairly new to programming and I have two buttons, one is camera the other is chooseExistingPhoto. I can access the camera functionality with the camera button and am trying to diplay the image that I take onto a UIImage in another view controller. My code is giving me an error of unable to render snapshot before it is taken. I assume that this is because I am also trying to use the button as a segue to display the new view controller. Is there a way to delay the segue action until after the user picks an image through their photo library or takes a photo?

@IBAction func camera(sender: AnyObject) {

```
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()

    picker.delegate = self
    picker.sourceType = .Camera

    presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)

    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Show", sender: self)


        func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!)
        {
            if segue.identifier == "Show" {
                imageDisplay.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
                dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

this is the code i have for my button. imageDisplay is an image outlet i created for the ImageView and to get this code to recognize it i made my ImageDisplayViewController a superclass to my main ViewController.

This is the error i am receiving.
Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates.

Comment: Post your code (attempt) here so that others will be able to understand your problem better and help you.

Comment: It sounds like you need to trigger the segue programmatically using `performSegueWithIndentifier` rather than triggering the segue directly from the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't assign segue from button to ViewController. Assign segue from ViewController to ViewController. Now when you have taken a picture from camera you will be redirected back to didfinishpicking delegate method in this method do self.performSegueWithIdentifer and select your controller from prepareforsegue. Lets say your segue name is show.

I have rewritten the code for you. Lets say your second VC is displayImageVC. Create a property there as showImage of type UIImage. Then in prepareforsegue pass the captured image.

```
var capturedImage = UIImage?
let picker = UIImagePickerController()     picker.delegate = self picker.sourceType = .Camera     presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil) 

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) { 
 self.capturedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
 self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Show", sender: self) 
}

func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) { 
if segue.identifier == "Show" { 
    let displayImageVC = segue.destination as displayImageVC
    displayImageVC.showImage = self.capturedImage
 } 
}
```

Comment: I added the segue from ViewController to ViewController and added that code and it is still saying i am trying to render and empty snapshot. Do I need to delay this code until after the image is taken somehow?

Comment: Where are you getting this error. Can you edit your question with the error. In prepare segue you have to pass the image which you have captured from camera. You have to add the performsegue at the end of didfinishPickingMediaWithInfo.

Comment: @Josh You have to get your basics strong first. How can you add the prepareforsegue inside the didfinishpicking... and where is this imageDisplay declare? If you want to display the image in new VC then yoi have to pass the image in prepareforsegue and then show in thd imageview there.

Comment: Okay. I definitely do need to work on the basics and I will. Thanks for all your help!